# OR operator in if condition is not working in plsql block

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

```
declare

myex exception;
no account.ano %type;
b account.bal%type;
branch account.Bname%type;

begin
no:=:no;
b:=:b;
branch:=:branch;

if branch <> 'surat'  then
raise myex;
end if;

insert into account values(no,b,branch);
commit;
dbms_output.put_line('record inserted successfully...');

exception
when myex then
dbms_output.put_line('invalid branch name ');
end;
```

This code is working properly just as expected but when I try to add more branch names in the if condition using or . Its not working . The exception is raised for all the entries even the valid branch names like surat or vadodra .

```
declare

myex exception;
no account.ano %type;
b account.bal%type;
branch account.Bname%type;

begin
no:=:no;
b:=:b;
branch:=:branch;

if branch <> 'surat' or branch <>'vadodra' or branch <>'ahmedabad' then
raise myex;
end if;

insert into account values(no,b,branch);
commit;
dbms_output.put_line('record inserted successfully...');

exception
when myex then
dbms_output.put_line('invalid branch name ');
end;
```

Comment: Because a single value cannot be equal to two different values. So if it is `'surat'`, then it is obviously not equal to `'vadodra'` and `if` condition is always true except null value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you most probably wanted `AND`, not `OR`:

```
if branch <> 'surat' and branch <>'vadodra' and branch <>'ahmedabad' then
```

Alternatively, use `IN`:

```
if branch not in ('surat', 'vadodra', 'ahmedabad') then
```